# More link not displaying on view. Why?

Tags: views

I created a view and am expecting the *More* link to appear but it isn't.

The *Content: Body field* formatter is set to *Trimmed* and the trim length is 100. *Create more link* is ticked, and I have entered "More" in the *More link text* text box.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you used the More link at the Pager section? That is for the view page, not what you need here. If your view mode is teaser, you get the more link if you have Display links set in Row style options. If your view mode is fields, then you can add a link to content field, which is not optimal, as it displays always. There are various solutions for that, even modules.

Answer (score 1):

You get a more link (that links to the node) if your view lists nodes in the teaser view mode. For any other case the situation is more complex.

Ongoing discussion about this issue: https://drupal.org/node/823380 "More link is always visible on teaser".

Perhaps the best solution for the time being:
https://drupal.org/project/readmorecontrol

Answer (score 0):

check node tpl for full and teaser view's, you may get a clue.